# Applying Wookmark tile plugin to a wordpress Theme using a posts-loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to apply the [Wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) jQuery Plugin to my wordpress theme. The implementation takes place with a Loop, as the point of the subject is to create a visually pleasing portfolio.
For the subject i've registered a new type of post typed 'portfolio' and made a loop that distinguishes between posts with pictures and those without.

The problem is of course, that it doesn't work. 
No returning errors, all scripts are in place [or so it seems to me] - but the posts do not receive whatever treatment [jQuery Voodoo] that the WookMark is supposed to apply. All I get all the posts, called in order.

I've enqueued the scripts into my theme through the functions.php file thus:

```
if ( !function_exists('core_mods') ) {
function core_mods() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/wookmark/libs/jquery.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script('wookmark', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/wookmark/jquery.wookmark.js', array('jquery-custom'), false, false);
    }           
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'core_mods' );
```

And the actual HTML of page-portfolio.php is as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php query_posts('post_type=portfolio') ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
            $('.masonry-object').wookmark({
                  align: 'center',
                  autoResize: false,
                  comparator: null,
                  container: $('#masonry-container'),
                  direction: undefined,
                  ignoreInactiveItems: true,
                  itemWidth: 0,
                  fillEmptySpace: false,
                  flexibleWidth: 0,
                  offset: 2,
                  onLayoutChanged: undefined,
                  outerOffset: 0,
                  possibleFilters: [],
                  resizeDelay: 50,
                  verticalOffset: undefined
            });
})(jQuery);
</script>
    <div id="masonry-container">
                <?php /* The loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="masonry-object" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                <div class="masonry-thumbnail">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('masonry-thumb'); ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="masonry-title">
                                        <?php echo the_title(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.masonry-thumbnail-->
                            <?php elseif ( !has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                                <div class="masonry-details">
                                    <h5>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                            <span class="masonry-post-title">
                                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </h5>
                                    <div class="masonry-post-excerpt">
                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    </div><!--.masonry-post-excerpt-->
                                </div><!--/.masonry-entry-details -->  
                            <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>
    </div> <!-- End .masonry-container -->  

<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The CSS attached to the subject is such:

```
#masonry-container {
}
.post-area {
    background: #ffffff ;
    padding: 10px ;
}
.masonry-thumbnail {
}
.masonry-thumbnail img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
.masonry-title {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #ef9430;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 0px ;
    right: 0px;
}
.masonry-details {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.masonry-object {
    width: 25% ;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.masonry-object:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffffff;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work. But thank you for helping me clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(function($) {...})(jQuery);` is not the same as `$(function() {...});`

First will be executed as soon as it is encountered, second one is jQuery shorthand for `$( document ).ready()`, and will run when the DOM is ready for JavaScript. The solution is to move the script below the `#masonry-container` div, or to use the ready event. There is a small problem in WordPress since default jQuery uses `jQuery.noConflict()` so $ is not referenced to jQuery object. My favorite solution for that is:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

});
```

It will run on document ready, with $ as a jQuery alias.

Side note: - use `position: relative` on `#masonry-container` div, as documentation says.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help~! I've been breaking my head over this for way too long.